# UrlFetchApp.fetch stopped working on Monday the 7th after no issues for months with two api's

Tags: api, google-apps-script, zendesk

Any one else see the following problem.

I use zendesk API and pipeline deals api.
code has been in use for 2 months (no issues all working)

As of this week (no changes to the code) both API's fail on post with create calls (Gets work fine and authentication also working fine for both API's).

The execution log shows correct data being encoded example below (removed actual values)

UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://supernahelp.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json, {headers={Authorization=Basic someencodedauthdata, Content-Type=application/json}, method=post, payload={"organization":{"name":"somecustomer","domain_names":"xyc.edu","organization_fields":{"supernauniqueid":"Sup-2308233814","crmdashboard":"someurladdedhere"}}}, muteHttpExceptions=true}])

The payload was passed through JSON.stringify to add to API call and has been working fine for ever.

Error return to from execution log  "call to make to ZD {"error":"RecordInvalid","description":"Record validation errors","details":{"name":[{"description":"Name: cannot be blank","error":"BlankValue"}"

Which basically means API could not parse the body correctly for the name value which was sent

I opened case with Zendesk and they got there logs and showed me what they received (not the same record)

only a snippet

{"{\"organization\":{\"name\":\"customer name here \"

I noticed \ added to the payload (not by my code) but this was added by GAS.

AND

Pipeline API has same issue payload Post commands are rejected with bad payload.

Both failed on the same day, and no longer work at all.

**this tells me others must have issue with post commands?
looking for help as code worked fine and then stopped and it looks like GAS is adding escape codes out of the blue**

Andrew

Comment: You can search existing issues in the issue tracker:  [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=URL+fetch&colspec=Stars+Opened+ID+Type+Status+Summary+Component+Owner&cells=tiles)  You might want to report what you are experiencing if you don't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

GAS was broken,  seems content type encoding into headers stopped working and moving the content type ad syntax was changed (broke many others scripts as well).

https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=5585&can=6&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Andrew